# use group by in mysql to aggregate 5-minute timestamp intervals

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, truncate

I have a mySQL database called crypto where inside I have a table called coin with three different columns: timestamp, price, volume.
The problem is the following: I want to group the data by timestamp in a period of 5 minutes, where the field price presents the maximum value and the field volume presents the sum.

I tried the following command:

```
SELECT sum(volume), max(price), 
round(unix_timestamp(addtime(date(0), timestamp) )/(15*60)) AS     
timestamp    
FROM btcusd_raw0
GROUP BY timestamp;
```

But it doesn't return the datetime as a column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about this as *truncating* a datestamp expression to the next lowest five-minute boundary.

How can you do that? This (long) expression works:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + 
            INTERVAL (MINUTE(datestamp) - MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 5) MINUTE
```

How does it work?

1. `DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')` gives the hour of the expression. For example, it turns `2001-09-11 08:42:00` into `2001-09-11 08:00:00` .
2. `(MINUTE(datestamp) - MINUTE(datestamp) MOD 5)` retrieves the minute (`42` in the example) and turns it to the next lowest five-minute boundary `40`.
3. `hourvalue + INTERVAL minutevalue MINUTE` adds the hour and minute together. `2001-09-11 08:40:00`

So, use this expression in your query, both in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

```
SELECT sum(volume), max(price), 
       DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + 
             INTERVAL (MINUTE(timestamp) - MINUTE(timestamp) MOD 5) MINUTE 
 FROM btcusd_raw0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00') + 
             INTERVAL (MINUTE(timestamp) - MINUTE(timestamp) MOD 5) MINUTE;
```

It makes for verbose queries. You might consider creating a stored function for it. [Here's a more complete explanation](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/).